# Should I use Table.cells[]?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, w3c

I'm currently trying to write some Javascript to loop through the elements in a table, but was wondering what the best practise was. I could just call `.cells[]` on my table object to get all of the cells in the table, but the W3Schools [page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp) says that this is not a W3C standard - should I avoid it then?

The other option is to use `.rows[]` to get all the rows (which is W3C Standard), then `.cells[]` on each of the rows (again, W3C Standard). Basically - how important is it that I stick to W3C Standard methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the standard exists, it's generally preferable to use it: there's more chance that it's well-supported in all your target browsers and wide adoption of standards helps prevent the proliferation of non-standard proprietary APIs.

This particular case is a no-brainer: the `cells` property of a `<table>` element isn't supported in Firefox, so you can't use it on the web.

Answer (score 2):

It is of the utmost importance to use standard APIs and properties as defined by the W3C. This ensures cross-browser compatibility, future-proofing and consistency.

Comment: How do you feel about `innerHTML`?

Comment: banzaimonkey: Delan's answer or my comment?

Comment: @Tim Down — While I try to avoid it (for a variety of reasons), it is part of a draft standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#innerhtml

Comment: Tim, strangely enough, I'm actually OK with innerHTML, as its support is ubiquitous.

Comment: David Dorward: yes, but as I'm sure you well know, that is a comparatively recent development. `innerHTML` is a prime example of something most people find extremely useful and existed with near universal browser support for many years without being part of any standard, while a well-supported but more unwieldy standard for doing the same thing already existed (DOM).

Comment: @Tim Down Delan's answer, for myriad reasons I think are obvious to someone who's been using html, css, and javascript for awhile.

Comment: banzaimonkey: I read it as sincere. That would've been a seriously dry bit of sarcasm.

Comment: ... or the many oddities it has in other browsers. IE's version was there first.